# Serialize Error during save file using DataContractSerialize

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, datacontractserializer

i use this code for serialize needed objects (use DataContractSerialier)

> ```
> try
> {
>  using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
>  {
>   var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
>   dcs.WriteObject(stream, obj);
>  }
> }
> catch (Exception ex)
> {
>  throw new Exception("Error during write object to xml file", ex);
> }
> ```
>
> i don't understand, but sometimes this method append to end of xml-file some additional symbols. for example :"eInfo>" ( when i deleted 'eInfo>' deserialization works good). i found this when do high load testing (call this method 12000 times without stoping). maybe i can checking that  file was saved correctly (try to deserialize saved file), but i think that it bad idea, because we need to run deserialize procees any time when save xml-file.

Comment: When you call the method 12000 times without stopping, are all of them writing to the same file? EDIT: Is the file on your local system or on a network share?

Comment: no, any time i save file with new file name to my local HDD drive.

Comment: Just to add, if it's to the same file, `File.OpenWrite` will _overwrite characters_ in the file, not clear the file first. That means if your last write (serialization) was _shorter_ than the previous write, it will leave left over characters. Read the remarks on the MSDN page for it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

That is because `File.OpenWrite` does not truncate the existing data. You are over-writing a file with *less data*. The garbage at the end is whatever was left over from the original file. I suggest you use `File.Create` (which is actually create or overwrite-with-truncate), or explicitly specify truncate, or call `.SetLength(0)` before writing.